# возможно ли сделать transition для ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы при наведении курсора на кастомный скроллбар он ПЛАВНО перекрашивался в другой цвет..
мой код:

```
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color:#181818;
    width:16px;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#181818;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#909090;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:4px solid #181818;
    background-clip: text;
    transition: .7s cubic-bezier(0,.8,.2,1);
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color:#606060;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {display:none}

.scrollbar {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример кода, как вы реализовали кастомный скроллбар

Comment: Можно. через js добавляйте/удаляйте класс для `.scrollbar` на события `mouseover, mouseout`, :hover просто через css повестить не получится на сколько я помню. ХОТЯ я не уверен попробуйте вот такую запись `.scrollbar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` еще

Comment: Я с js не очень дружу, недавно только начал увлекаться html и css